# How to create a Docker image for PHP and Node?

Tags: php, node.js, docker

I am trying to create a Docker container for my Angular app that has a PHP file in it. Angular requires npm so I need to have Node.js installed. I don't need Apache for my project, just pure php should work fine.

My understanding is I should have a docker-compose like this:

```
FROM node:latest

..install php here

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app
```

I am not sure how to install PHP in my case, Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest you do it differently. Since php is longer than install, use the php image and install node.

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm
#WORKDIR is /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html/
RUN npm install
```

And then you have apache2 provides .php files.

**Update for 2021**
It is recommended to use `php:7.4-apache` or newer.

Comment: Nodejs seems to be installed but I am getting npm: not found error as it seems npm is not available. +1 tho

Comment: Sorry I missed npm package.

Comment: If you are using alpine based solution then try following:

"RUN apk add --update nodejs npm"

Comment: Should this be `... apt-get install -y nodejs npm`? (note:  "nodejs" vs "node")

Comment: I've used this solution , thanks for share

Comment: That works, but it installs a very old version of NPM (version 7.5.2). I need a newer version (10.1.0). I think I will need to go the other way around. Install PHP in node docker.

Comment: Just in case, the `nodejs` repository mentioned is not official, like https://nodesource.com/. It's not recommended I would say since it's not monitored and is from still awesome Community. Please consider checking out https://nodejs.org/en/download instead for production.

Answer (score 45):

I think in this case the better way is to use node docker image and PHP docker image together like below and not install one of them by using `apt-get install`

```
FROM node:latest AS node
FROM php:7.4-fpm

COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node_modules
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app
```

in this way you don't need to install either node or PHP package every time that you change your code and rebuilding from scratch is required in your Dockerfile

**Update:** I have noticed recently that the node is relocated into the `include` path, at least it looks like it on the Alpine, so that you can replace `/usr/local/lib/node` with `/usr/local/include/node` for the alpine images.

for `node:21-alpine` the configuration is like this.

```
FROM node:21-alpine AS node
FROM php:8.3-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache libstdc++ libgcc

COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node_modules
COPY --from=node /usr/local/include/node /usr/local/include/node
COPY --from=node /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
COPY --from=node /usr/local/share/doc/node /usr/local/share/doc/node
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
COPY --from=node /opt/ /opt/
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npx
RUN ln -s /opt/yarn-$(ls /opt/ | grep yarn | sed 's/yarn-//')/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn
RUN ln -s /opt/yarn-$(ls /opt/ | grep yarn | sed 's/yarn-//')/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg
```

**Caution:** You must install `libstdc++` and `libgcc` packages on the Alpine so the node works properly.

the `$(ls /opt/ | grep yarn | sed 's/yarn-//')` part is for finding the image yarn version under the `/opt/` path.

Comment: this worked for me. The build ran fine and I have the latest node and npm installed now. Thanks

Comment: This worked for me. I also used php-express to execute php scripts from the express server.

Comment: This results in: /bin/sh: 87: node: not found when trying to rund node or in: /usr/bin/env: 'node': No such file or directory when trying to run npm. It seems like something is missing here.

Comment: Make sure that both images are based on the same distro if you are experiencing the "no such file" error https://stackoverflow.com/a/74238155/799588

Comment: Thanks for your idea. In my case, I had to make some changes to make it work for my environment. I specified the node version with:
FROM node:16-alpine AS node
COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node_modules
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin

After that the installation went ok.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the node docker image (eg. slim) which is build on top of Debian.
And use `apt` to just install PHP cli.

```
FROM node:lts-slim
ENV NODE_ENV production
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

WORKDIR /app

# Install PHP (used for post-deployment commands)
RUN apt update && apt install -y php-cli php-intl php-mbstring php-xml php-zip

# Continue with your NodeJS package....

COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json

.....
```